# In Processing.js, how to declare an object type and an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, processing.js

I learned processing.js through Kahn academy, where you declare any type of variable simply by using `var`.  However, I see that instead of `var`, terms like `int` and `float` are used.  But how do you declare an object type?  And, how do you declare an array of objects?  Below is the relevant code that works fine in the the realm of Kahn Academy.  Can you tell me how I would rewrite the lines that use `var`?  Many thanks.

```
var Mover = function (xPos, yPos, cloudColor){
    this.xPos = xPos;
    this.yPos = yPos;
    this.cloudColor = cloudColor;
};


var movers = []; 

//I know the var below gets replaced with “int”:

for (var i = 0; i <=1000; i++){
    movers[i] = new Mover(random(-22,width), random(-22,height), random(188,255));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your question, you want to translate your code from [processing.js](http://processingjs.org) based on JavaScript to [processing](https://www.processing.org) based on Java. You can do it like this:

```
class Mover{
  float xPos, yPos;
  float cloudColor;
  public Mover(float xPos, float yPos, float cloudColor){
    this.xPos = xPos;
    this.yPos = yPos;
    this.cloudColor = cloudColor; 
  }
}


ArrayList<Mover> movers = new ArrayList<Mover>(); 
for (int i = 0; i <1000; i++){
   movers.add(new Mover(random(-22,width),
                        random(-22,height),
                        random(188,255)));
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's it!  It turns out that the essential line to change was the one about declaring an array of objects.  The one you offered: Mover[] movers = new Mover[1000]; solved everything and the code runs fine.

Comment: If you think that the answer is right, click on the up arrow at the left of the answer.

Comment: technical note: it's "Processing", not "the java version of Processing". Processing is a language on its own with its own defined programming model and API, based on but different from Java. And yes, it will happily run on the JVM **if compiled to java first** (straight up trying to compile .pde code without first translating it to Java will fail)

Comment: the JavaScript array, however, maps to the Processing (and Java) ArrayList, so you'd use `ArrayList<Mover> movers = new ArrayList<Mover>();` and then just `movers.add()`, `movers.get()` and `movers.remove`. Also, JS has no int (all JS numbers are floating point), so make those positions `float` and then no int casting will be required.